# How to achieve something similar to struct functionality without using any compound data structures?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on an assignment (writing my own dynamic memory allocator) that forbids me from creating any global compound data structures whatsoever (arrays, structs, whatever).

However, it seems extremely useful to me to have a `header` structure defined, maybe something like this:

```
struct header {
    size_t size;
    struct header *next_p;
    struct header *prior_p;
};
```

Without being able to do this, how can I easily keep track of this information? I need to just have this info written right into the header of the current memory block, and I can read it from there?

Even more generally, if you're not familiar with allocators, what is an effective way to achieve the organization of a `struct` while only being allowed to use scalars

Comment: You would use a global `struct`. Honestly, the requirement is either stupid or you misunderstood it. But instead of a global `struct header`, you could also allocate each variable individually.

Comment: @FUZxxl it says "You are not allowed to define any global or static compound data structures such as arrays, structs,
trees, or lists in your mm.c program. However, you are allowed to declare global scalar variables such
as integers, floats, and pointers in mm.c. Thus, you may use scalar variables as root nodes for tree or
list structures superimposed on blocks in the heap"

If I break this rule, I get a zero. I think it is stupid as well. What do you mean to allocate each variable individually? Just create all three variables contained in the header upon each allocation of a block?

Comment: Allocate a pointer to a header structure. A pointer seems to be allowed. And before I meant, instead of making one global `struct header`, make global `size_t gl_size; struct header *gl_next_p, *prior_p;`

Comment: @FUZxxl Sure but in making a pointer to a header structure, I have to make the header structure? I don't see why that would be allowed

Comment: Put the header structure itself into a memory region you create. Where do you get the memory you allocate from?

Comment: To me it seems the requirement is poorly worded. Intent seems to be to avoid creating compound *variables* with static storage duration. I don't see reason why it would disallow defining global *types*, which you'd allocate dynamically.

Comment: @user694733 But doesn't a global type need to be a reference to a global struct of some sort?

Comment: It makes no sense to limit scope of struct *type* definition. In my opinnion you are allowed to A) Define `struct header` type as you have shown. B) Define global pointer of that type `struct header * rootNode;`. C) Allocate memory for it `rootNode = malloc(sizeof(*rootNode));` Restriction seems to disallow defining global *variable* directly: `struct header rootNode;`.

Comment: @user694733 I'm not allowed to call `malloc` either, since I'm supposed to be writing a `malloc` myself. Either way, wouldn't doing it this way still allow me to do the same kind of things with it as I would If I did just create a global struct variable? Seems to just be a loophole in the instructions, and I don't want to get a zero because I misunderstood a technicality.

Edit: why is it confusing that the rule says "You are not allowed to define any global... data structures such as... structs...". Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use structs or array in any form, then all that is left is manually counting offsets and pointer arithmetric. But that's a error prone as you can easily mess up pointer alignment if you are not careful. It's hard to explain what you need to do as we don't know the big picture. By the way, what do you use as a memory pool for your custom malloc, if you are not allowed to define global byte array for it?

Comment: @user694733 I know it's error prone, the lab manual says that it will be hard and will reuire a ton of pointer arithmetic. And honestly man, I just don't know.

Comment: *Global data structures* usually imply something that is allocated in memory. Thus type definitions shouldn't fall into this category. But if you want to be sure, you should ask for clarfication from the one giving you the assignment.

Comment: @jphollowed A type doesn't refer to any objects at all; it's not stored anywhere. A "global structure" is a value (`struct data x;`), not a `struct` definition in the global scope (`struct data { int a; };`).

Comment: I agree with @molbdnilo. The intent of the restriction is that you don't declare global variables for book keeping. Instead the booking structures must be embedded within the memory blocks that you are managing. So you can define structs but there must be no variables of those struct types. Instead you need to have pointers/indexes into the managed memory which track the structs. That's what it means by "superimposed". If you read the restriction like that it makes much more sense.

Comment: To further clarify. This is not allowed: `struct header free_blocks[MAX_FREE_BLKS];`. This is allowed: `struct header *free_list = (struct header *)MANAGED_MEM_START_ADDR;`

Comment: This requirement seems a bit odd as I don't understand the rationale behind not using some of the basic compiler constructs. You could allocate a control page and use that to store the data you need.

Are you implementing a user space memory allocator for a hobby project ? Or is it in the kernel. Even malloc uses brk and sbrk to reserve memory. And maintains control information in reserved pages.

Can you comment on why do you have such a restriction.

Comment: @linuxmonk this is a lab for class, I am to write my own malloc

Comment: @jphollowed Then I suppose you could use the reserved page to maintain your data as a series of bytes. Since they are all in a page they are as good as a struct but not really a struct. You could then use mlock() system call to lock the page/pages followed by using brk/sbrk to allocate/free memory. Like the paging structures maintained in the linux kernel. Is that what you're looking for ?